# How to get gradle/pod files in ReactNative project

Tags: android, ios, react-native, gradle, cocoapods

I'm trying to develop my first react-native app. Before I used capacitor, that creates for me the android/ios platforms inside my angular/react project and threat them just as normal assets.

ReactNative instead didn't create anything beyond my regular typescript project (**I used expo-cli to setup**). Problems arise when I try to use `react-native-charts-wrapper`, that asks me to manipulate gradle/pod file to use it ([doc](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper/blob/master/installation_guide/README.md)).

Thinking in general terms, it seems pretty weird that my project totally miss the android/ios native assets.

What am I  missing? So what I'm supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that to get the android/ios projects I need to setup my project with `react-nativle-cli` intead of `expo-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `expo-cli`, try `react-native-cli`, that resolved the same issue when I had faced it.